Node.js firebase uid Swift/Xcode
I currently am trying to understand how to get the user who is currently signed into my Swift/Xcode app with firebase to then get this uid in my Node.js file so I can save my stripe event directly to their child. I am not sure of how the communication would work so hopefully someone can help lead me to some documentation or code on how this could be achieved. Thank you!
    const admin = require("firebase-admin");

    // This code works for event sends events correctly
exports.events = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const endpointSecret = ''
  const stripe = require('stripe')(functions.config().stripe.token);
  const payloadData = request.rawBody;
  const webhookStripeSignatureHeader = request.headers['stripe-signature'];
  const firebaseUid = admin.auth.uid

  let event;
    // Get the signature sent by Stripe
    try {
      event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(payloadData, webhookStripeSignatureHeader, endpointSecret);

      return admin.database().ref('/user_profiles/' + firebaseUid).push(event) // Add the event to the database
      .then((snapshot) => {
        // Return a successful response to acknowledge the event was processed successfully
        return response.json({ received: true, ref: snapshot.ref.toString() });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err) // Catch any errors saving to the database
        return response.status(500).end();
      });
      
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(`⚠️  Webhook signature verification failed.`, err.message);
      response.status(400).send();
  }
  // Handle the eventfirebase 
  switch (event.type) {
    case 'payment_intent.succeeded':
      const paymentIntent = event.data.object;
      console.log(`PaymentIntent for ${paymentIntent.amount} was successful!`);
      response.status(200).send({ msg: "Success", object: paymentIntent});
      break;
    default:
      // Unexpected event type
      console.log(`Unhandled event type ${event.type}.`);
  }
  // Return a 200 response to acknowledge receipt of the event
  response.status(200).send();
});


It seems there are two questions: 1) how to get the user who is currently signed into my Swift/Xcode app and 2) save my stripe event directly to their child. Is the code presented not working? If so, can you clarify and reduce the question to just one, and then indicate where the code is not working. Also, the question appears to be using Admin and there's a section in the documentation about how to get information about a user Manage Users. Please clarify and update the question
